# Why limit $\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ is not a real number?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

Let 
$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}$.

Why isn't the $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ equals to some $l \in \mathbb{R}$?

The definition of a finite limit at inifinity is:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists X \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \ge X,|f(x)-l| <\epsilon  \tag{1}$$

It looks to me that $l=0$ meets the above definition...

I know that the negation of the definition of a finite limit at infinity is:
$\exists \epsilon >0 , \forall X \in \mathbb{R}, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}, x\ge X \Rightarrow  |f(x)-l| >=\epsilon \tag{2}$

Is $(2)$ true because, for any $X\in \mathbb{R}$, there will be an $x\ge X$ and $f(x)$ is undefined (i.e. the points where $\frac{\sin(x)}{x} < 0$) and we say the distance between $f(x)$ at these points and any $l\in\mathbb{R}$ is undefined and hence considered as greater than or equal to any $\epsilon > 0$? If yes, how do I write this out using the delta-epsilon proof? Otherwise, please tell me how to prove $(2)$

EDIT:

The definition for a finite limit and infinity according to my text is:

> We say that $f(x)\rightarrow l$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ for some real number,$l$, if:
>
> for any $\epsilon>0$, there is an $X$ such that, for all $x\ge X$, $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$

Comment: $\sqrt{\sin x/x}$ is not well-defined (as real-valued function) if $(2n-1)\pi<x<2n\pi$ for $n\in\Bbb{Z}$. But if you consider $\sqrt{\sin x/x}$ as complex-valued function, $\sqrt{\sin x/x}$ goes to 0 as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Your definition is wrong in the sense that's not the usual, nor equivalent to the usual definition.

Comment: @GitGud I may have wrongly restated the definition. In that case, I've copied the definition exactly as it appeared in my text.

Comment: @mauna Analysts write wrong things all the time. What you copied isn't sufficient to judge the 'correctness' of the definition because it doesn't explain what $f$ is. If there is an assumption that the domain of $f$ contains an interval of the form $]a,+\infty[$, for some $a\in \mathbb R$, then it is correct. (From this you can already see why your limit doesn't exist). Otherwise, it's badly written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be that the definition of the limit requires that $f(x)$ is defined for all sufficiently large $x$. But to me, a more sensible definition could be written as
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists X \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x \ge X\text{ with }x\in D_f,|f(x)-l| <\epsilon  \tag{3}$$
where $D_f$ is the domain of $f$. With this definition, it must be an additional requirement that for any $X\in\mathbb{R}$, there are some $x\ge X$ with $x\in D_f$.

I think you will find that most mathematicians will go for this definition, whereas some elementary texts will go for the more restricted definition, in the interest of simplicity.